# external links with parameters shouldn't reach pages

Tags: java, spring, bots, external-links

My website has prices which you can reach in a page. Has some parameters ex: date, people number etc. When you select/assign this parameters. javascript loads a page into div. It works great. But a couple of days ago I realized that some bots get prices with external links with parameters.

I have a solution in my mind. This is to prevent external links to reach my specific page. Have you any solutions to solve this problem in Java Spring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want this information to be freely accessible, why do you expose it on the web without any kind of authentication necessary to access it?

Comment: Customers are able to see, Our site and informations are also public. Our competitors have written bot which gets information of all products at the same time. And sometimes they send wrong parameters, we can catch these error. But a couple of days error mails have increased. For this reason should we find a solution.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly now? That your error handling code sends too many mails?